# Why I still have this error detached entity passed to persist: User - SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, many-to-many

my problem is with detach entity passed to persist.

```
    org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: User; nested exception is 
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: User; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: User

    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:280)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:225)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy151.findAllBySalesPointIdIn(Unknown Source)
    at OrganizationResolver.getOrganizationsFromDataBase(OrganizationResolver.java:124)
    at OrganizationResolver.persistOrganizations(OrganizationResolver.java:89)
    at com.inteca.bnmt.ldap.resolver.OrganizationResolver$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3125662c.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
```

Oracle Database:

If a create a new clear schema is successfully executed only once, then the problem still pops up.
in UserRepository and OrganizationRepository I use @EntityGraph, to get eager.

Entity:

User.class

```
@MappedSuperclass
abstract public class AbstractUser extends AbstractEntity {

@Basic(optional = true)
@Column(name = "cn")
private String cn;

  @ManyToMany(cascade =  {
        CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}
    , fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "User_organization", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "UserId")
    , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "organizationId")
    )
    private java.util.Set<Organization> organization = new java.util.HashSet<Organization>(); }
```

Organization.class

```
@MappedSuperclass
abstract public class AbstractOrganization extends AbstractEntity {

  @ManyToMany(cascade =  {
        CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}
    , mappedBy = "organization", targetEntity = User.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private java.util.Set<User> user = new java.util.HashSet<User>();
}
```

My final code:

UserService.class

```
 @Transactional
    public User createUpdate(User user, LdapUser ldapUser) {

        log.info("START - createUpdateUser");

        /* Resolve dnAdGroups */
        user = adGroupResolver.adGroupsResolver(user, ldapUser);

        /* Resolve functionalRoles and persist */
        user = functionalRoleResolver.functionalRolesResolver(user);

        /* Resolve organization and persist */
        user = organizationResolver.persistOrganization(user); **<---- inside**

        /* Persist primary and User.Organization */
        user = organizationUResolver.checkPrimaryOrganization(user);

        /* OperatorId addition sequence */
        if ((user.getOperatorId() == 0)) {
            user.setOperatorId(setNewOperatorId(user));
        }
        log.info("Trying to save user {} in DB", user);
        user = userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
        log.info("User {} updated successfully!", user);

        return user;
    }
```

OrganizationResolver.class

```
   @Transactional
    public User persistOrganization(User user) {

        Set<String> strings = ResolveUtils.cutLdapDnAdGroupsToGetSalesPointId(user, workplaceDn);

        Set<Organization> organizationFromDataBase = getOrganizationsFromDataBase(user.getDataSource(), strings); **<---- inside**

        if (organizationsFromDataBase.containsAll(user.getOrganization()) && user.getOrganization().containsAll(organizationsFromDataBase))
            return user;

        /* 1. remove from user.organizations NOT match organizationsFromDataBase */
        Set<String> collectSalesPointId = organizationsFromDataBase.stream()
                .map(AbstractOrganization::getSalesPointId)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        Set<Organization> collect = user.getOrganization().stream()
                .filter(organization -> !(collectSalesPointId.contains(organization.getSalesPointId())))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        user.getOrganization().removeAll(collect);

        /* 2. remove from organizationsFromDataBase ALL EXISTING in user.organizations */
        Set<String> collectName1 = user.getOrganization().stream()
                .map(AbstractOrganization::getSalesPointId)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        Set<Organization> collectExistingInUser = organizationsFromDataBase.stream()
                .filter(organization -> collectName1.contains(organization.getSalesPointId()))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        organizationsFromDataBase.removeAll(collectExistingInUser);

        /* 3. add ALL from organizationsFromDataBase to user.organizations */
        user.getOrganization().addAll(organizationsFromDataBase);

        return user;
    }

    Set<Organization> getOrganizationsFromDataBase(String dataSource, Set<String> organizationIds) {
        Set<Organization> foundOrganizations = new HashSet<>();
        if (organizationIds.isEmpty()) return foundOrganization;

            foundOrganizations = organizationRepository.findAllBySalesPointIdIn(organizationIds); **<---- detach error !!!!!**


        if (!foundOrganizations.isEmpty())
            log.info("Organizations {} found successfully", foundOrganizations.size());
        else
            log.info("Organizations not found");

        return foundOrganizations;
    }
```

Thank you, for any help.

Comment: You can upvote this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53470282/managing-many-to-many-relationship-with-hibernate/53471097#53471097 it's related with your question, bidirectional is not possible to apply using Oracle database

Comment: @nextsoft I do not agree with this, I have bidirectional in many projects with an oracle base.

Comment: Yes but on JPA is not allowed with oracle database, that is reason why you get the error @Daniel

Comment: @nextsoft , I just fix that problem. Now everything looks perfect. Thank you for help, but you, are wrong from the beginning.